# Designing a Card class using Enums - Pros/Cons of 2 different designs

Tags: java, enums

I am weighing 2 different designs to implement a Card class.

- Using 2 different Enums: one for **rank**, one for **suit**
- Using only 1 Enum

  - *Ace_Of_Spades*
  - *Two_Of_Spades*
  - *(ect)*

I am thinking that the first design is more flexible, and it allows us to
implement the methods we would usually want to use on cards more easily. If we were to use just one `enum`, then methods like `getRank()` or methods to compare the cards or to sort them would be a bit more messy.

I am wondering if anyone could give me more insight on the advantages/disadvantages of design 2 compared to design 1?

**Thank you.**

Comment: What makes you even consider the 2nd design?

Comment: It is more of a thought exercise, I am trying to learn more about how to write good software/choose good designs.

Comment: You can take a look at this documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/enums.html
I believe you can find it useful

Comment: What type should `getRank()` return in the second case? Further, consider that there are card sets having two of each kind.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with the first option. These are two different properties of a card, I don't see any reason to store them together. It's much more flexible to keep them apart.

Generally speaking, I think a field should describe only one characteristic of the class, so a field like 'suitAndRank' is by definition wrong